# how to create a tar archive on mac

Tags: macos, mac

My instructor asks to submit HW by creating a new tar archive of the top-level directory. Can anyone tell me what does the "top-level directory" mean. Can I just change the folder extension to .tar? I am using Mac.

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal window.

```
tar -zcvf archive_name.tar.gz Folder to compress. 
tar -zxvf archive_name.tar.gz
```

As far as top-level directory. 
That all depends on what directory the home work is in. Say /home/users/john/homework ? Without knowing your directory structure, I can't answer that for sure. Though the tar commands I gave you above will at least zip the folders you need.